# PYTHON - grep command: wrong output, exit status 2

Tags: python, grep, binary, subprocess, encode

I trying to find a Pattern in specific large files (GB) in subfolders

I am runnging Python code.

1. tried....

> ```
> FILE_PATH=/folder1/FILE.txt - OK, absolute path
>
> with open (FILE_PATH, "r") as FILE:
>   for index, x in enumerate(FILE):
>     if re.findall(".*TEXT.*", x):
>       ...takes too much time...
> ```

2. another way

in Bash from terminal:

> ```
> grep -a 'TEXT' /folder1/FILE.txt - output OK as desired
> ```

Python code:

> ```
> FILE_PATH=/folder1/FILE.txt - OK, absolute path
>
> STATUS=(subprocess.check_output("grep -a \'TEXT\' " + str(FILE_PATH.encode()), shell=True)).rstrip('\n')
>
> I get this output in terminal
> ...: Command 'grep -a 'TEXT' b'/folder1/FILE.txt'' returned non-zero status 2
> ```

Any advice, please?

How to run Bash GREP command in Python on both binary/text file with variables (File path) ang store grep output into Variable in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use os.popen(), which should mimic and return the result you see when using the bash command:

```
import os
FILE_PATH = "/folder1/FILE.txt"
results = os.popen(f"grep -a 'TEXT' {FILE_PATH}").read()
print(results)
```

Comment: what does the ...f... stands for? - os.popen(f"grep..... I can not find it in manual

Comment: @Scripter It's an f-string, you can look it up. :)